# Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04. Hangs in random stop during installation

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 22.04

Linux noob here. I have installed Ubuntu on several different computer (Mac & PC) without problem.

I'm having a installation problem with an old Acer Laptop

- Acer Aspire ES-15 ES1-533-c9D0
- 256G Sata 3 Drive (currently Windows 10 Home. Will be replace by Ubuntu)
- Intel Celeron N3350 - 1.1 Ghz
- Intel HD Graphics 520
- 4GB Memory

Secure Boot is Disabled

I have tried editing the Grub boot command by adding nomodeset or i915.modeset=0.  I have no idea if it's a graphics issue or not.  This is the only thing I could find on the web. Nothing helped.

The installation seems to hang in different places on each installation trial. I have attach a screenshot of the approximate area it hangs.

Any ideas on how to fix or what to try?

[image: install pic]

Comment: Test the RAM. Look up how to use MEMTEST

Comment: Does it run the Live system from USB without issues, i.e. does the error only occur during installation? (BTW: are you sure you want ZFS on such a small memory system?)

Comment: Memtest is fine.  It runs Windows 10 Home fine now.  I don't know what ZFS is. What is it? I just built the standard Ubuntu 22.04 installer.  That is what I have always used. It hangs before I can Try Ubuntu.